# How to convert two letter currency code to base locale identifier on IOS

Tags: identifier, nslocale, country-codes

I need to convert my two letter country code, to its default, native, identifier, e.g. TW > zh_TW not en_TW. US > en_US. RU > ru_RU, not en_RU. IT isn't justg the same two letters repeated. Note, I need to do this from the COUNTRY code, not the language code. Is there a simple way, using NSLocale, or do I have to have a big list !?

Thanks

Shaun Southern

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *countryCode = @"IE";

NSDictionary *components = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countryCode forKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];

id localeIdent = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:components];                        
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdent];
```